# Написание слов "прецедент" и "инци(н)дент"

Tags: орфография

Все время путаюсь в написании слов "прецедент" и "инци(н)дент". Где нужна буква Н, а где нет? Или вообще нигде не нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в словарь заглянуть раз и навсегда?
Нигде не нужна.

Вернее нужна в словах корреспондент, респондент, претендент и еще нескольких сугубо специальных. Можете запомнить, что все они - люди. 
А инцидент и прецедент - события.

Comment: Тоже удивляюсь. Многие участники смогли найти форум, зарегистрироваться, а проверить по словарю (не в книге, так в Сети) не могут!

Comment: Давайте тогда совсем форум закроем. Зачем он нужен, если все можно посмотреть в словаре? Если люди обращаются за помощью, отвечайте. Вам же не трудно.
Администратор.

Comment: Не надо доводить до абсурда. Ответить бывает не трудно, но смысл?  
Я понимаю, что форуму любой вопрос на пользу, поисковые инлексы рулят...  

Но все-таки есть вещи, которые гораздо логичнее смотреть в словаре. Тем более если человек жалуется, что не может запомнить. Неужели ответ на форуме решит проблему запоминания? А активный поиск в словаре таки заставит запомнить.

Comment: @behemothus, вот Вы и молодец... Неправильно написали. Не "корреспонтдент", а "корреспондент".

Comment: исправил...

Comment: > Зачем он нужен, если все можно посмотреть в словаре?

Ну, правильно. Лентяев развелось. Но хочу обратить внимание на то, что можно что-либо выучить, но потом все равно это забудется, а если что-то понять, т.е. найти логику, алгоритм, то потом всегда можно вспомнить как правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Упрекнуть спрашивающих в лени, конечно, можно, но этот элементарный вопрос можно сформулировать и иначе. Оба слова произошли от латинских форм incidentis -случающийся и   prаecеndentis - идущий впереди, предшествующий. Как видим, во втором случае в слове есть согласный "n". Может, от этого и происходит такая путаница в написании этих слов? Не очень внимательны были наши предки, когда вводили в обиход иностранные слова, не обеспечивая единого подхода к написанию.

Comment: Ну, в английском есть чудесное слово [precede][1].

 [1]:http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precede

Comment: prаecеndentis - в латинском, подтверждаю. Но немного в другом значении. И при этом исходная форма там все равно prаecеdents.
В русский пришло явно не напрямую из латыни.

Comment: Хочу ссылку на prаecеndentis

Comment: Я взял это слово латинское из обычного "Словаря иностранных слов"

Comment: А вообще, вы знаете, похоже это действительно тиражируемая ошибка.
Я-то воспринял это гугловское "prаecеndentis" (в т.ч. и на страницах на латыне) как некое другое значение. Но нигде не нашел подтверждения. Видимо, просто ошибка в родительном падеже (правильно - praecedentis). Но расползлась, зараза...

Comment: > Я взял это слово латинское из обычного "Словаря иностранных слов"

брешет, похоже, ваш словарь. Я тоже сначала купился.  
Тут - ни разу:  
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/970014

А вот и источник заразы: ))
http://yas.elcode.ru/